# Proof of Convergence of Exponential When Defined as the Limit of a Sequence of Functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove that the sequence $(1 + \frac{z}{n})^n$ converges, for any complex $z$, without using the equivalent series definition of $exp$ or the properties of the complex logarithm. All I need is pointwise convergence. I've tried expanding the sequence by the binomial theorem, but the fact that the number of summands in the expansion depends on the position in the sequence seems to prevent me from moving forward.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try comparing this series with $1 + z + z^2/2! + \ldots$ using the binomial theorem? I think that should work

Comment: what properties of $a^b$ would you allow for $a,b∈\Bbb C$, if you don't allow properties of the complex logarithm?

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Didn't read that you didn't want to use the other series definition of $\exp$.

Comment: I'm hoping to not need any properties of $a^b, b \in \mathbb{C}$. In the definition of $exp$ I've given, the power is just an integer so, from first principles at least, it doesn't seem immediately necessary to use those properties. Perhaps it is though; I would just like this technique of building $exp$ to be more "contained".

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ converges for every $x∈\Bbb R$. Then 
$$\left( 1+a+ib\right)^n = \left( 1+a\right)^n\left(1 + \frac{ib}{1+a}\right)^n$$
using $a=x/n,b=y/n$, we reduce by product rule and continuity to needing to show the result for purely imaginary $z=0+iy/n$, since
$$\left(1 + \frac{iy/n}{1+x/n}\right)^n = \Big(1 + \frac{iy}{n} - \underbrace{\frac{ixy}{n(x+n)}}_{=O(n^{-2})}\Big)^n$$

For $(1+\frac{iy}{n})^n$, we avoid the complex logarithm by using the geometrically defined(say) $\arg$ function, which satisfies the log-like rule
$$ \arg \left(1+i\frac{y}{n}\right)^n =  n \arg \left(1+i\frac{y}{n}\right) = n \arctan \frac{y}{n}$$
(up to a multiple of $2π$, but lets choose that multiple to be 0.)
Since 
$$ n\arctan \frac{y}{n} = y \frac{\arctan(0+y/n)-\arctan(0)}{y/n} \xrightarrow[n→∞]{} y$$
But note also that $$\left|\left(1+\frac{iy}{n}\right)^n\right| = \left|1+\frac{iy}{n}\right|^n = \left(1+\frac{y^2}{n^2}\right)^{n/2} → 1$$ By properties of the real exponential which I'm assuming. Hence by the polar representation of complex numbers we have that $(1+iy/n)^n → e^{iy}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :**

Let $z_n = 1+\frac{z}{n}$ and $u_n=(z_n)^n$.

We can write $u_n = r_n \exp(i \theta_n)$. To show that $(u_n)$ converges, it is sufficient to show that $r_n$ and $\theta_n$ converge.

---

Let $z = a + ib$.

---

$r_n = |u_n| = |z_n|^n = (1+ 2\frac{a}{n} + \frac{a^2 + b^2}{n^2})^{\frac{n}{2}}$. Then you can show  that $r_n$ converges to $e^{a}$.

---

$\theta_n = \arg(u_n) = n \arg(z_n) = n \arctan(\frac{\frac{b}{n}}{1+\frac{a}{n}}) = n \arctan(\frac{b}{n+a})$  Similarly you can show that this converges to $b$.